# Bing Custom Search API Not Detecting Keywords on Provided URLs

Tags: web-scraping, search-engine, bing-search, search-engine-api, bing-custom-search

I am currently working with the Bing Custom Search Engine API to search for specific keywords within provided URLs. However, I am facing an issue where the API is unable to detect the keywords on the given URLs, even though I can personally verify that the keywords are present when I manually visit the URLs.

Here's a summary of the problem:

1. I am using the Bing Custom Search Engine API to search for keywords on provided URLs.
2. When I visit the URLs myself, I can confirm that the desired keywords are present within the content of    those pages.
3. However, the Bing Custom Search Engine API is not able to retrieve the keywords from these URLs.
4. Interestingly, the API successfully detects the keywords when I provide a URL, and the keywords are located within the subpages of that URL.

This inconsistency in keyword detection is puzzling, and I'm unsure why the API behaves in this manner. I have double-checked my implementation to ensure that I am properly interacting with the API and passing the correct parameters.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with the Bing Custom Search Engine API or any other search API? Are there any potential reasons for this behavior? Is there a way to troubleshoot and improve the API's ability to retrieve keywords from the main content of provided URLs?

Any insights, suggestions, or experiences related to this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!